# Gradle Apk build. faild (:applyRetrolambda FAILED)

Tags: java, spring, gradle, build.gradle, gluon

I am trying to migrate a maven project to gradle. so far i'v had success with the 'run Task' (the app is running in eclipse fine) but i am failing to generate an apk file.

build.gradle file:

'`

```
    buildscript {
        ext {
            springBootVersion = '2.0.3.RELEASE'
        }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.12'
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'io.rainrobot.wake'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

mainClassName = 'io.rainrobot.wake.android.GluonApplication'

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.1.3'
    compile ('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpasyncclient:4.1.3') {
    exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging' 
 }
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: '4.1.3'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence', name: 'hibernate-jpa-2.1-api', version: '1.0.0.Final'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.9.5'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.9.5'

    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: '5.0.6.RELEASE'

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jta-narayana:1.5.9.RELEASE')
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', module: 'tomcat-embed-websocket' 
 }

}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.8.0'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'

            androidSdk='C:/Users/Roy 1/android-sdks'
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}
```

`'

consule output:

```
    Working Directory: C:\Users\Roy 1\eclipse\workspaces\wake\app
Gradle User Home: C:\Users\Roy 1\.gradle
Gradle Distribution: Gradle wrapper from target build
Gradle Version: 4.8.1
Java Home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131
JVM Arguments: None
Program Arguments: None
Build Scans Enabled: false
Offline Mode Enabled: false
Gradle Tasks: android

> Task :validateManifest
> Task :collectMultiDexComponents
> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileAndroidJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :processAndroidResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :androidClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :copyClassesForRetrolambda

> Task :applyRetrolambda
Retrolambda 2.5.3
00:00  INFO: Bytecode version: 50 (Java 6)
00:00  INFO: Default methods:  true
00:00  INFO: Input directory:  C:\Users\Roy 1\eclipse\workspaces\wake\app\build\javafxports\tmp\android\retrolambda\input
00:00  INFO: Output directory: C:\Users\Roy 1\eclipse\workspaces\wake\app\build\javafxports\tmp\android\retrolambda\output
00:00  INFO: Classpath:        [C:\Users\Roy 1\eclipse\workspaces\wake\app\build\javafxports\tmp\android\retrolambda\input, C:\Users\Roy 1\android-sdks\platforms\android-27\android.jar]
00:00  INFO: Included files:   all
00:00  INFO: JVM version:      1.8.0_131
00:00  INFO: Agent enabled:    false
00:12  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/server/RequestPredicate$$Lambda$1
00:12  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/ipc/netty/http/server/HttpServerRoutes$$Lambda$1
00:12  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/ipc/netty/http/server/HttpServerRoutes$$Lambda$2
00:12  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/ipc/netty/http/server/HttpServerRoutes$$Lambda$3
00:12  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/boot/devtools/restart/classloader/ClassLoaderFileRepository$$Lambda$1
00:12  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/boot/devtools/restart/FailureHandler$$Lambda$1
00:12  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/core/Scannable$$Lambda$1
00:12  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/core/Scannable$$Lambda$2
00:12  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/core/Scannable$$Lambda$3
00:14  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/security/authorization/ReactiveAuthorizationManager$$Lambda$1
00:14  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/security/authorization/ReactiveAuthorizationManager$$Lambda$2
00:14  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/security/authorization/ReactiveAuthorizationManager$$Lambda$3
00:14  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/source/IterableConfigurationPropertySource$$Lambda$1
00:14  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/util/context/Context$$Lambda$1
00:14  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/util/context/Context$$Lambda$2
00:14  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/ipc/netty/NettyContext$$Lambda$1
00:14  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/ipc/netty/NettyOutbound$$Lambda$1
00:14  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/ipc/netty/NettyOutbound$$Lambda$2
00:14  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/ipc/netty/NettyOutbound$$Lambda$3
00:14  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/ipc/netty/NettyOutbound$$Lambda$4
00:14  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/ipc/netty/NettyOutbound$$Lambda$5
00:14  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/ipc/netty/NettyOutbound$$Lambda$6
00:14  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/ipc/netty/NettyOutbound$$Lambda$7
00:14  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/ipc/netty/NettyOutbound$$Lambda$8
00:14  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/ipc/netty/NettyOutbound$$Lambda$9
00:14  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/ipc/netty/NettyOutbound$$Lambda$10
00:16  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/server/HandlerFilterFunction$$Lambda$1
00:16  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/server/HandlerFilterFunction$$Lambda$2
00:16  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/server/HandlerFilterFunction$$Lambda$3
00:16  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/server/HandlerFilterFunction$$Lambda$4
00:16  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/server/HandlerFilterFunction$$Lambda$5
00:16  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/server/HandlerFilterFunction$$Lambda$6
00:16  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ExchangeFilterFunction$$Lambda$1
00:16  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ExchangeFilterFunction$$Lambda$2
00:16  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ExchangeFilterFunction$$Lambda$3
00:16  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ExchangeFilterFunction$$Lambda$4
00:16  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ExchangeFilterFunction$$Lambda$5
00:16  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ExchangeFilterFunction$$Lambda$6
00:16  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/boot/devtools/remote/server/AccessManager$$Lambda$1
00:16  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/ipc/netty/resources/PoolResources$$Lambda$1
00:16  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/ipc/netty/resources/PoolResources$$Lambda$2
00:17  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/source/ConfigurationPropertyName$CharProcessor$$Lambda$1
00:17  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/source/ConfigurationPropertyName$CharProcessor$$Lambda$2
00:17  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/ipc/netty/http/websocket/WebsocketOutbound$$Lambda$1
00:17  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/ipc/netty/http/websocket/WebsocketOutbound$$Lambda$2
00:17  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/boot/devtools/restart/RestartInitializer$$Lambda$1
00:17  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture$$Lambda$1
00:17  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture$$Lambda$2
00:18  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/bind/PlaceholdersResolver$$Lambda$1
00:18  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/boot/util/LambdaSafe$Filter$$Lambda$1
00:18  INFO: Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/layout/Layer$$Lambda$1
00:18  INFO: Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/layout/Layer$$Lambda$2
00:19  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/boot/devtools/settings/DevToolsSettings$$Lambda$1
00:22  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/core/MethodParameter$$Lambda$1
00:23  INFO: Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/cloudlink/client/data/RemoteFunction$$Lambda$1
00:23  INFO: Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/cloudlink/client/data/RemoteFunction$$Lambda$2
00:23  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/util/concurrent/WaitStrategy$$Lambda$1
00:23  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/jmx/export/MBeanExporter$$Lambda$1
00:23  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/jmx/export/MBeanExporter$$Lambda$2
00:23  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/jmx/export/MBeanExporter$$Lambda$3
00:23  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/jmx/export/MBeanExporter$$Lambda$4
00:23  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/jmx/export/MBeanExporter$$Lambda$5
00:23  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/core/scheduler/PeriodicSchedulerTask$$Lambda$1
00:23  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/boot/diagnostics/analyzer/InvalidConfigurationPropertyValueFailureAnalyzer$$Lambda$1
00:23  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/boot/diagnostics/analyzer/InvalidConfigurationPropertyValueFailureAnalyzer$$Lambda$2
00:23  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/boot/diagnostics/analyzer/InvalidConfigurationPropertyValueFailureAnalyzer$$Lambda$3
00:23  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/DeferredResultMethodReturnValueHandler$$Lambda$1
00:23  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/ipc/netty/channel/FluxReceive$$Lambda$1
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/ipc/netty/channel/FluxReceive$$Lambda$2
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/ipc/netty/channel/FluxReceive$$Lambda$3
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/ipc/netty/channel/FluxReceive$$Lambda$4
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/ipc/netty/channel/FluxReceive$$Lambda$5
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/result/method/annotation/ControllerMethodResolver$$Lambda$1
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/result/method/annotation/ControllerMethodResolver$$Lambda$2
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/result/method/annotation/ControllerMethodResolver$$Lambda$3
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/result/method/annotation/ControllerMethodResolver$$Lambda$4
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/result/method/annotation/ControllerMethodResolver$$Lambda$5
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/result/method/annotation/ControllerMethodResolver$$Lambda$6
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/result/method/annotation/ControllerMethodResolver$$Lambda$7
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/result/method/annotation/ControllerMethodResolver$$Lambda$8
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/result/method/annotation/ControllerMethodResolver$$Lambda$9
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/result/method/annotation/ControllerMethodResolver$$Lambda$10
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/result/method/annotation/ControllerMethodResolver$$Lambda$11
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/result/method/annotation/ControllerMethodResolver$$Lambda$12
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/result/method/annotation/ControllerMethodResolver$$Lambda$13
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/ipc/netty/resources/DefaultLoopResources$$Lambda$1
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/boot/devtools/restart/classloader/RestartClassLoader$$Lambda$1
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/boot/devtools/restart/classloader/RestartClassLoader$$Lambda$2
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/BodyExtractors$$Lambda$1
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/BodyExtractors$$Lambda$2
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/BodyExtractors$$Lambda$3
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/BodyExtractors$$Lambda$4
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/BodyExtractors$$Lambda$5
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/BodyExtractors$$Lambda$6
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/BodyExtractors$$Lambda$7
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/BodyExtractors$$Lambda$8
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/BodyExtractors$$Lambda$9
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/BodyExtractors$$Lambda$10
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/BodyExtractors$$Lambda$11
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/BodyExtractors$$Lambda$12
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/BodyExtractors$$Lambda$13
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/BodyExtractors$$Lambda$14
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/BodyExtractors$$Lambda$15
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/BodyExtractors$$Lambda$16
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/BodyExtractors$$Lambda$17
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/BodyExtractors$$Lambda$18
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/BodyExtractors$$Lambda$19
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/BodyExtractors$$Lambda$20
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/BodyExtractors$$Lambda$21
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/BodyExtractors$$Lambda$22
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/BodyExtractors$$Lambda$23
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/BodyExtractors$$Lambda$24
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/BodyExtractors$$Lambda$25
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/BodyExtractors$$Lambda$26
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/BodyExtractors$$Lambda$27
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/result/method/annotation/RequestHeaderMethodArgumentResolver$$Lambda$1
00:24  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/filter/reactive/ForwardedHeaderFilter$$Lambda$1
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/filter/reactive/ForwardedHeaderFilter$$Lambda$2
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/filter/reactive/ForwardedHeaderFilter$$Lambda$3
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/core/publisher/ParallelFlux$$Lambda$1
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/core/publisher/ParallelFlux$$Lambda$2
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/core/publisher/ParallelFlux$$Lambda$3
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/core/publisher/ParallelFlux$$Lambda$4
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/core/publisher/ParallelFlux$$Lambda$5
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/core/publisher/ParallelFlux$$Lambda$6
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/core/publisher/ParallelFlux$$Lambda$7
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/core/publisher/ParallelFlux$$Lambda$8
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/core/publisher/ParallelFlux$$Lambda$9
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/core/publisher/ParallelFlux$$Lambda$10
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/core/publisher/ParallelFlux$$Lambda$11
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/core/publisher/ParallelFlux$$Lambda$12
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/core/publisher/ParallelFlux$$Lambda$13
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/ipc/netty/tcp/TcpServer$Builder$$Lambda$1
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/ipc/netty/tcp/TcpServer$Builder$$Lambda$2
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/ipc/netty/ByteBufMono$$Lambda$1
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/ipc/netty/ByteBufMono$$Lambda$2
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/ipc/netty/ByteBufMono$$Lambda$3
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/ipc/netty/ByteBufMono$$Lambda$4
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: reactor/ipc/netty/ByteBufMono$$Lambda$5
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction$$Lambda$1
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction$$Lambda$2
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction$$Lambda$3
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction$$Lambda$4
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction$$Lambda$5
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/FloatingActionButton$a$$Lambda$1
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/FloatingActionButton$a$$Lambda$2
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/FloatingActionButton$a$$Lambda$3
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/FloatingActionButton$a$$Lambda$4
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders$$Lambda$1
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders$$Lambda$2
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders$$Lambda$3
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders$$Lambda$4
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders$$Lambda$5
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders$$Lambda$6
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders$$Lambda$7
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders$$Lambda$8
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders$$Lambda$9
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders$$Lambda$10
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders$$Lambda$11
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/util/concurrent/ListenableFutureTask$$Lambda$1
00:25  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/util/concurrent/ListenableFutureTask$$Lambda$2
00:26  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/boot/util/LambdaSafe$Callbacks$$Lambda$1
00:26  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/boot/util/LambdaSafe$Callbacks$$Lambda$2
00:26  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/boot/util/LambdaSafe$Callbacks$$Lambda$3
00:26  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/boot/util/LambdaSafe$Callbacks$$Lambda$4
00:26  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/boot/util/LambdaSafe$Callbacks$$Lambda$5
00:26  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/boot/util/LambdaSafe$Callbacks$$Lambda$6
00:26  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/security/web/server/authentication/AuthenticationWebFilter$$Lambda$1
00:26  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/security/web/server/authentication/AuthenticationWebFilter$$Lambda$2
00:26  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/security/web/server/authentication/AuthenticationWebFilter$$Lambda$3
00:26  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/security/web/server/authentication/AuthenticationWebFilter$$Lambda$4
00:26  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/security/web/server/authentication/AuthenticationWebFilter$$Lambda$5
00:26  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/result/view/script/ScriptTemplateView$$Lambda$1
00:26  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/result/view/script/ScriptTemplateView$$Lambda$2
00:27  INFO: Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/ExceptionDialog$$Lambda$1
00:27  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/DefaultClientRequestBuilder$BodyInserterRequest$$Lambda$1
00:27  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/DefaultClientRequestBuilder$BodyInserterRequest$$Lambda$2
00:27  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/DefaultClientRequestBuilder$BodyInserterRequest$$Lambda$3
00:27  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/DefaultClientRequestBuilder$BodyInserterRequest$$Lambda$4
00:27  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/result/method/AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$$Lambda$1
00:27  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/result/method/AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$$Lambda$2
00:27  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/boot/security/reactive/ApplicationContextServerWebExchangeMatcher$$Lambda$1
00:27  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/boot/security/reactive/ApplicationContextServerWebExchangeMatcher$$Lambda$2
00:27  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/server/RouterFunctions$FilteredRouterFunction$$Lambda$1
00:27  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/bind/support/WebRequestDataBinder$$Lambda$1
00:27  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/beans/CachedIntrospectionResults$$Lambda$1
00:27  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/beans/CachedIntrospectionResults$$Lambda$2
00:27  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/beans/CachedIntrospectionResults$$Lambda$3
00:27  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/server/DefaultServerResponseBuilder$AbstractServerResponse$$Lambda$1
00:27  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/web/reactive/function/server/DefaultServerResponseBuilder$AbstractServerResponse$$Lambda$2
00:27  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/http/client/InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution$$Lambda$1
00:27  INFO: Saving lambda class: org/springframework/http/client/InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution$$Lambda$2
00:27 ERROR: Failed to run Retrolambda
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to backport class: org/springframework/http/server/reactive/UndertowServerHttpResponse
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.Transformers.transform(Transformers.java:129)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.Transformers.transform(Transformers.java:107)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.Transformers.backportClass(Transformers.java:47)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.Retrolambda.run(Retrolambda.java:92)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.Main.main(Main.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to backport lambda or method reference: org/springframework/http/server/reactive/UndertowServerHttpResponse.lambda$applyHeaders$0(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/List;)V (7)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.lambdas.LambdaReifier.reifyLambdaClass(LambdaReifier.java:44)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.lambdas.BackportLambdaInvocations$InvokeDynamicInsnConverter.backportLambda(BackportLambdaInvocations.java:194)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.lambdas.BackportLambdaInvocations$InvokeDynamicInsnConverter.visitInvokeDynamicInsn(BackportLambdaInvocations.java:183)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.asm.ClassReader.readCode(ClassReader.java:1519)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1032)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:708)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:521)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.Transformers.lambda$transform$4(Transformers.java:107)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.Transformers.transform(Transformers.java:125)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: no such method: org.springframework.http.server.reactive.UndertowServerHttpResponse.lambda$applyHeaders$0(String,List)void/invokeSpecial
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName.makeAccessException(MemberName.java:867)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:1003)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.resolveOrFail(MethodHandles.java:1386)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.findSpecial(MethodHandles.java:1004)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.lambdas.Types.toMethodHandle(Types.java:53)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.lambdas.Types.asmToJdkType(Types.java:26)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.lambdas.LambdaReifier.callBootstrapMethod(LambdaReifier.java:117)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.lambdas.LambdaReifier.reifyLambdaClass(LambdaReifier.java:39)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/undertow/server/handlers/Cookie
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.resolve(Native Method)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolve(MemberName.java:975)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:1000)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.undertow.server.handlers.Cookie
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.NonDelegatingClassLoader.loadClass(NonDelegatingClassLoader.java:27)
    ... 21 more

> Task :applyRetrolambda FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':applyRetrolambda'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 50s
6 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you want to port to Android that app with all those dependencies?

If that's the case, I'm afraid it won't be possible.

When the retrolambda task fails in your case:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to backport class: org/springframework/http/server/reactive/UndertowServerHttpResponse
...
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.undertow.server.handlers.Cookie
```

the reason is a `ClassNotFoundException`, what means that the dependency is not available.

In other words, you need to resolve all the transitive dependencies of your build.gradle list for the Android tasks.

In this case, the problem with the Spring framework is its use of `optional` for dependencies.

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26220205/3956070), it seems all the `optional` dependencies have to be manually added (like `runtime` or `androidRuntime` dependency).

In this case, the list of[optional dependencies](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/spring-web.gradle) is quite big. The same goes for all the different related frameworks, like `spring-core`.

I took the time to add one by one all the required dependencies to pass the retrolambda task:

```
runtime('io.undertow:undertow-core:2.0.11.Final')
runtime('io.undertow:undertow-servlet:2.0.11.Final')
runtime 'org.springframework:spring-jms:5.0.6.RELEASE'
runtime 'javax.jms:javax.jms-api:2.0'
runtime 'org.springframework:spring-context-support:5.0.6.RELEASE'
runtime 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.3.8'
runtime 'io.reactivex:rxjava-reactive-streams:1.2.1'
runtime("org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:9.4.11.v20180605") {
    exclude group: "javax.servlet", module: "javax.servlet-api"
}
runtime("org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:9.4.11.v20180605") {
        exclude group: "javax.servlet", module: "javax.servlet-api"
}
runtime('org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:9.4.11.v20180605') {
    exclude group: "javax.servlet", module: "javax.servlet-api"
}
runtime('org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-servlet:9.4.11.v20180605') {
    exclude group: "javax.servlet", module: "javax.servlet-api"
}
runtime('org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:9.4.11.v20180605') {
    exclude group: "javax.servlet", module: "javax.servlet-api"
}
runtime 'org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:4.0.1.RELEASE'
runtime 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:5.0.6.RELEASE'
runtime 'org.infinispan:infinispan-core:9.3.1.Final'
runtime 'org.infinispan:infinispan-commons:9.3.1.Final'
runtime 'javax.websocket:javax.websocket-api:1.1'
runtime 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-async:3.8.0'
runtime 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
runtime 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.1.8.RELEASE'
runtime 'io.searchbox:jest:5.3.3'
runtime 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client:5.0.6.RELEASE'
runtime 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose:5.0.6.RELEASE'
runtime 'com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:3.5.1'
runtime 'com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-mapping:3.5.1'
runtime 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-cassandra:2.0.9.RELEASE'
runtime 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-core:3.0.8.RELEASE'
runtime 'com.querydsl:querydsl-core:4.2.1'
runtime 'org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:2.0.5.RELEASE'
runtime 'io.micrometer:micrometer-core:1.0.6'
runtime 'net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:2.10.5'
runtime("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.2.51")
runtime("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.51")
runtime 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.3.3.Final'
runtime 'org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:6.0.11.Final'
runtime 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core:5.1.4'
runtime "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.11.0"
runtime "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.11.0"
runtime 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.6.2'
runtime 'org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring5:3.0.9.RELEASE'
runtime 'com.couchbase.client:core-io:1.6.0'
runtime 'com.hazelcast:hazelcast:3.10.4'
runtime 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
runtime 'javax.enterprise:cdi-api:2.0.SP1'
runtime 'com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-core:1.5.12'
runtime 'org.aspectj:aspectjtools:1.9.1'
runtime 'com.couchbase.client:couchbase-spring-cache:2.1.0'
runtime 'org.webjars:webjars-locator-core:0.35'
runtime 'org.springframework:spring-orm:5.0.6.RELEASE'
runtime 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.6'
runtime 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:2.27'
runtime 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:1.1.1'
```

So now you will pass the retrolambda task, but then you will run into the next issue:

```
> Task :GluonApplicationTestApp:mergeClassesIntoJar FAILED
Execution failed for task ':GluonApplicationTestApp:mergeClassesIntoJar'.
> archive contains more than 65535 entries.
```

If you check the folder `\build\javafxports\tmp\android\retrolambda`, you will notice that there 500 MB of more than 150000 `*.class` files. And even if you could create a dex file with all those entries, the size of the application will be huge.

In conclusion, you should check for other [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39579540/spring-boot-on-android) that don't involve adding a huge back-end into a client mobile app.

You can check for instance this [sample](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/spring-motd) that uses Spring in the back-end, and Gluon Mobile in the client, with CloudLink to connect both.

Comment: Thanx! I'v discarded the boot dependencies for plain spring and it passed. very informative and helpful!